# Expected value of the negative portion of sum of poisson random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expectation, law-of-large-numbers, poisson-distribution

**Setting:**

Defn: for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ define its negative part by $x^{-} = -x$ if $x \leq 0$, and $x^{-} = 0$ if $x > 0$

Let $\{X_j, j \ge 1\}$, $X_j \overset{d}{\sim} Poisson(1) = \Pr\{X = k\} = \frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$ for $k \geq 0$.

Let $\{S_n , n \ge 1\}$ corresponding sequence of partial sums.

Let $T_n = \frac{S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}}$

I want to show $\pmb{E}[T_n^-] = \frac{n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n}}{n!}$

**My Solution**

First I massaged the expression into a statement about the tails, although I am not sure the result is correct:
$$ \pmb{E}[T_n^-] = \pmb{E}[T_n \pmb{1}_{(-\infty,0]} (T_n)] = \pmb{E}\left[ \frac{S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} \pmb{1}_{(-\infty,0]} (T_n)  \right]
= \pmb{Pr}\Big\{ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} < 0 \Big\}$$

where I recognized that

$$\pmb{E}\left[ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\pmb{E}[X_1 + \ldots + X_n] 
  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\pmb{E}[X_1] + \ldots + \pmb{E}[X_n]) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

So we have
$$\pmb{E}[T_n^-] = \pmb{Pr}\Big\{ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \pmb{E}\left[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right] < 0 \Big\} 
  = 1 - \pmb{Pr}\Big\{ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \pmb{E}\left[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right] \ge 0 \Big\} $$

Now this is where I am really uncertain, what is the variance? my argument is that

$$ Var\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \pmb{E}\left[\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \pmb{E}\left[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\right)^2\right]
  =  \pmb{E}\left[\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right]
  =  \pmb{E}\left[\frac{S_n^2}{n} - 2 \frac{S_n n}{n} + \frac{n^2}{n}\right]\\
  = \frac{1}{n} \pmb{E}[S_n^2] - 2 \pmb{E}[S_n] + n = \frac{n^2}{n} - 2 n + n = 0$$

But clearly this cannot be correct since if it is, then we have by Chebyshev's inequality on the last term:

$$\pmb{Pr}\Big\{ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \pmb{E}\left[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right] \ge \epsilon \Big\} \le \frac{Var(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})}{\epsilon^2}
  \rightarrow^p \frac{0}{\epsilon^2} = 0$$

Which is not the result I would like to arrive at.

$$\pmb{E}[T_n^-] = 1 - \pmb{Pr}\Big\{ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \pmb{E}\left[\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right] \ge 0 \Big\} = 1 - 0 = 1$$

So where did I go wrong?
P.S. Stirling's formula may be useful here, but currently I found no use for it.

Comment: The two first mistakes are in the line $$ \pmb{E}[T_n^-] = \pmb{E}[T_n \pmb{1}_{(-\infty,0]} (T_n)] = \pmb{E}\left[ \frac{S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} \pmb{1}_{(-\infty,0]} (T_n)  \right]
= \pmb{Pr}\Big\{ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}} < 0 \Big\}$$
since $\pmb{E}[T_n \pmb{1}_{(-\infty,0]} (T_n)]$ should read $-\pmb{E}[T_n \pmb{1}_{(-\infty,0]} (T_n)]$, and since there is no reason to say that the last $\pmb{E}$ is actually a $\pmb{Pr}$.

Comment: Got something from the answer?

Comment: Yup the key is to recognize sum of poisson random variables is poisson itself (which should be common sense but apparently not to me), that considerably simplifies the algebra! Thanks for following up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $S$ denote any Poisson random variable with parameter $n$, then $$\mathrm e^{n}E((n-S)^+)=\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)\frac{n^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n^k}{(k-1)!}.$$ The change of variable $i=k-1$ in the last sum on the RHS yields $$\mathrm e^{n}E((n-S)^+)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^{i+1}}{i!}=\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}.$$ Surely you can conclude from here.